# Data-Driven list of numerical measures in a view returning as strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, generics, razor

I've got a list of Measures in a database:

```
         Measures
ID    DisplayOrder    Name
------------------------------
1          3          Homework
2          2          Quiz
3          1          Exam
4          4          SomeBigInt
...etc
```

Some of these measures are represented as `Int`s, some are `Double`s.

I'm trying to come up with a way to get all these measures out of the database and make displays for them:

### Model

```
namespace MyProj.BusinessRepository.BuisnessModels
{
    public interface IMeasure
    {
        Int32 Id { get; set; }
        String Name { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// The position in which the measure should be displayed
        /// </summary>
        Int32 DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    }

    public class ScoreMeasure<T> : IMeasure
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public T Adjustment { get; set; }
        public T BaseValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class AdminMeasure<T> : IMeasure
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public T Weight { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Which I then use inside a parent model as a list (which is wrapped in a  ViewModel).

After reading up on various other questions on SO, it looks like the only way to do this (given multiple types) is as a `List<ScoreMeasure<Object>>`.

### View

```
    for(var i=0; i < Model.ScoreCard.Measures.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.ScoreCard.Measures[i].Name)
        @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.ScoreCard.Measures[i].Adjustment).Append("%").Label().LabelText(Model.ScoreCard.Measures[i].Name)
    }
```

It's working, but the adjustments are coming back as strings (which I suppose makes sense since I had to use `Object` as my generic parameter).

Is there a smarter way to get these recognized as numbers? As is, unobtrusive validation doesn't enforce the numeric constraint, and I have to parse them when they come back (not sure how I'm going to tell which are Int vs Double other than maybe looking for a decimal point, which could be removed by the user)?

ETA: Don't be confused by the funky `@f.formGroup()` stuff in the view, that's TwitterBootstrapMVC-- essentially it's wrapping a `@Html.TextBoxFor`.

Comment: So the `T` could represent an `int` or `decimal`?  Is there any reason you can't just use `decimal` to represent the numbers and have you models tell MVC which template to use to render it?

Comment: @Justin My main concern about just making them all `Double`s is rounding/precision errors and other "funny" math that might occur. ETA: Could you show an example of what you mean by having the models tell MVC which template to use to render?

Comment: Justin said decimal, not double, decimal is more precise.

Comment: I suppose that would work! Feel kinda silly asking, in retrospect. @Justin, still interested in hearing how you could have MVC distinguish the right way to render it-- just a flag like `isInteger`, I suppose? Or a 3rd class like `IntScoreMeasure`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question about how to format the value, you can decorate your model with the `DisplayFormat` attribute.  This used in conjuncture with the `Html.DisplayFor` or `@Html.DisplayForModel` method to render it.

```
public class MyModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n0}" ,ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal IntValue { get; set; }

    public decimal DecimalValue { get; set; }
}
```

Using the object initializer of `var model = new MyModel {DecimalValue = 2.546m, IntValue = 245.110m};` shows they are decimal, but the `DisplayFor` and `EditorFor` methods will now format it to appear as an int to the user.

You can also use Editor and Display templates to accomplish this and decorate your property with the `UIHint` attribute to tell the `DisplayFor` and `EditorFor` methods to use the templates you create to render it.